# Combinatorial interpretation of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

A book that I am reading suggests the following exercise

Suppose we have $n > 2$ objects blue colored bins, red colored bins and some uncolored bins. Show that Fermat's Last Theorem is equivalent to the statement that

> The number of ways of putting the objects into bins so that the bins of both colors are shun is never equal to the number of ways to put the objects into the bins so that neither color is shun.

The book also hints at defining $x$ to be the number of bins that are not blue, $y$ the number of bins that are not red and $z$ the total number of bins.

As far as I can come from here is that the above statement (if true) would imply $(x+y-z)^n = z^n - x^n - y^n$ and I don't see how to proceed from here.

Anyone happens to know how to prove the equivalence?

Comment: I haven't seen the word "shun" used as you have here, could you explain what it means in this context?

Comment: @Scoot H. Neither did I but I suppose it means "to completely avoid" or something

Comment: Ah, it makes sense now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that we have some (at least one) red bins and some (at least one) blue bins. The number of ways to put the $n\gt 2$ balls into coloured bins, so that every ball is in a bin of the same colour, is never the same as the number of ways to put the balls into uncoloured bins.

If we use the above formulation, let $x$ be the number of red bins, $y$ the number of blue, and $z$ the number of uncoloured. The first paragraph says that $x^n+y^n$ is not equal to $z^n$. One had to insist that there be at least one each of red and blue to rule out trivial solutions like $x=z$, $y=0$.