# FLT (Fermat): Combinatorial approaches?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request

Such a simple equation like $x^n+y^n=z^n$ is bound to have a nice/natural combinatorial interpretation. One very crude one is: Let the number of ways of choosing $n$ objects from $x$ objective, without replacement, be $(x,n)$. Then $(x,n)+(y,n)=(z,n)$ is impossible.

This doesn't seem to give any light on the problem, but it's just an example. My question is have there been powerfulcombinatorial approaches to FLT in the past?

Comment: I am not aware of such an approach, and I don't think it could help too much, in the sense that it could replace one of the hard mathematics used in FLT so far (from algebraic and arithmetic grometry, number theory, representation theory, modular forms etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Quine published [this paper](http://logic.sysu.edu.cn/Soft/UploadSoft/200801/20080111142254403.pdf), which presents a combinatorial reformulation; Ribenboim presents a more rigorous statement and proof in his *Fermat’s Last Theorem for Amateurs* (pp. 250–251).

[Here’s another paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0196885896905102).

There are probably other similar attempts — but whether or not they’re “powerful” is up for debate.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469933/combinatorial-interpretation-of-fermats-last-theorem